# datetimeオブジェクトを、ISO8601形式（末尾"Z"かつミリ秒まで）の文字列に変換したいです。どのように書くのがシンプルでしょうか？

Tags: python

## 環境

- Python3.8

## やりたいこと

datetimeオブジェクトをISO8601形式の文字列にしたいです。具体的には以下の要件を満たしたいです。

- 末尾が"Z"
- ミリ秒まで出力

以下のように `strftime` 関数を用いて出力すると、マイクロ秒まで出力されてしまいます。

```
import datetime
dt=datetime.datetime(2021,1,1,2,3,4,123456, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
expected = "2021-01-01T02:03:04.123Z"
actual = dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(actual)
# '2021-01-01T02:03:04.123456Z'
```

## 質問

上記の要件を満たす文字列を生成するには、どのように書くのがシンプルでしょうか？
以下のように書けば要件は満たせますが、文字列操作の部分が分かりづらいと感じています。

```
tmp = dt.isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")
print(tmp)
# 2021-01-01T02:03:04.123+00:00
actual = tmp[0:23] + "Z"
print(actual)
# 2021-01-01T02:03:04.123Z
```

便利な方法やライブラリがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

簡単, かもしれない方法

```py
print(dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds').replace('+00:00', 'Z'))
```

少し面倒かもしれない方法

```py
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime, timezone
class TZ(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        pass
    def dst(self, dt):
        return timedelta(0)

dt = datetime(2021,1,1,2,3,4,123456, tzinfo=TZ())


print('{}Z'.format(dt.isoformat(timespec='milliseconds')))
```

Comment: 文字列のスライス操作よりは、replaceメソッドを使った方が分かりやすいですね。

Comment: TZクラスを作っている理由は何でしょうか？`tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc`を指定するだけで、よいと思いました。

Comment: `utcoffset` メソッドで値を返さないことにより, `+00:00` を付けないという役割です。使い方によっては処理を短くできるので，